# Modifier "Adjust Edit Cage" - Is there a way to make transformations relative to modifier result instead of the original mesh?

Tags: modifiers, edit-mode, transforms

When I select vertices on the resulting edit-cage, the transform tool appears over the original mesh instead of actual vertices I selected on the modifier result. Similarly, if I move the vertices, they move relative to the original mesh.

This makes editing the mesh very tedious without being forced to apply the modifier result first, at which point the changes aren't applied to any mirrored / arrayed portions of the object.

What's the correct approach to this? Is this a feature that exists or will be added at some stage, or am I going about this the wrong way?

[image: Selection screenshot]

Comment: I don't think there's any solution available for the moment, it's a thing that should be suggested to the Right Click Select site, for example if you want to edit the mesh of a character that is deformed by an armature, the gizmo won't take the modifier into account, it will be located on the vertex  position before modifier, which is not convenient at all.