# How to Snap Cursor to Selected, but accounting for the Modifier result?

Tags: modifiers, interface, snapping, coordinates, 3d-cursor

[Snap `Cursor to Selected`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/editing/snap.html) places your cursor at the selected vertex of your mesh (or the mean of *multiple* selected vertices).

The trouble is that sometimes the vert you want to place the 3D Cursor at is in its current position *because of a Modifier*.

Consider the example screenshot below:

[image]

↑ Here, snapping the 3D Cursor to the selected vert *did not* place it at the location of the vert.

The snapping operation placed it where the vertex *was* before the Shrinkwrap Modifier affected it.

Well, obviously there are cases when we want to know where a vertex is *now*, not where it *was* before modification.

I thought one logical place to look for a setting to change the Snap behavior might be in the Sidebar the the **Transform** panel. After all, there is a toggle switch there to display info for `Global` versus `Local` values. It would be a fitting place for a checkbox to `Use Modifier Result`, but no such checkbox exists.

[image]

Another consideration was that maybe the snap behavior could be changed by clicking the buttons to enable a modifier's ***Edit Mode** - “Display modifier in Edit Mode”* button and ***On Cage** - “Adjust edit cage to modifier result”*. But of course, that is not the case, as I already had them enabled when I tried snapping. I'm just including mention of them here for the sake of completeness, as one might expect them to have an effect on snapping behavior.

[image]

<sup>Above: Buttons enabled for Edit Mode and On Cage</sup>

Sure, one obvious workaround would be to **Apply** the modifier, **Snap**, and then **Undo** the application of the modifier. (This trick works because thankfully the 3D Cursor's location is not counted in Undo steps.) But even using this workaround, things can get hairy if you've got a large modifier stack, or when snapping must be done repeatedly.

Is there a **setting** or optional **parameter** that can be invoked with a shortcut key so that Snap operations take Modifiers into account?

Comment: Hey :). I don't think it's possible. The 3D cursor simply moves to the Gizmo position, but gizmos don't take modifiers into account. I remember Brecht saying it's not a bug, but a low priority feature... [related](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/194817/78972)